# Execute Junit tests on classes in Android Studio without initialising mobile device / emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit

Is there a way to execute a test in Android Studio for a specific class without a mobile device being used as the testing environment? I would like the tests to execute on my development machine instead. The classes in question do not contain any Android specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem with Android development and one that has been solved by [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/). This allows your tests to run on the JVM and can therefore be ran within Android Studio. The example below is taken from their website.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyActivityTest {

  @Test
  public void clickingButton_shouldChangeResultsViewText() throws Exception {
    MyActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);

    Button button = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView results = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.results);

    button.performClick();
    assertThat(results.getText().toString()).isEqualTo("Robolectric Rocks!");
  }
}
```